# "Time since request" in wireshark

Tags: http, time, response, wireshark

I have a http conversation capture. In a response packet (chunked response), there is a field called "Time since request". Is this field the "Time-to-First-byte" or the "Time-to-Last-byte"?

Comment: This is configurable and answered [here](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/46537/time-since-request-httptime). In future, questions that only involve Wireshark should be asked on [Wireshark forums](https://ask.wireshark.org).

Comment: @RossJacobs, Thank you.